# Execute bat file in asp.net localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, iis-7, batch-file

Hi i am trying to execute bat file in asp.net. it runs in developer/IIS Express but dosnt in IIS. i think there something with permissions. Thanks.

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
  myProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Data\MyFile.bat");
  myProcess.Start();
  myProcess.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your permissions on the `C:\Data\` folder. Make sure the `IIS_IUSRS` has read and execute permissions.

otherwise If an application pool is configured to run using the Application Pool Identity feature then a "synthesised" account called `IIS AppPool\<pool name>` will be created on the fly to used as the pool identity. In this case there will be a synthesised account called `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` created for the life time of the pool. You can add this account to `C:\Data\` folder permissions to grant access to your application.